# What's the difference between "made of" and "is made of" the passive voice issue!

Tags: passive-voice

I came across a sentence from LongMan dictionary while I was looking up the word "fence", and the phrase example was: a structure made of wood, metal etc that surrounds a piece of land.
my question is: why the sentence wouldn't be: a structure IS made of wood,...
"is made of wood" instead of "made of wood" since we talk about passive voice?!!
please explain to me that issue..

Comment: Dictionary definitions are shaped to match definendum syntactically, so as to be able to substitute for it in a sentence. Since the sense of *fence* here in question is as a simple noun, the addition of the verb *is,* so as to make this a complete passive-voice sentence, would be step in the wrong direction.

Comment: It's not even clear to me that this is a passive construction.

Comment: If we were discussing a specific fence then we would say something like "The fence around the paddock is made of wood". However a dictionary definition is discussing fences in the abstract. In this case we either say "A fence is a structure made of wood, metal, etc" or "A fence is a structure _which is_ made of wood, metal, etc"

Answer (score 1):

*A fence is a structure made of wood* means the same thing as

> A fence is a wooden structure.

In the dictionary, you will look up the word *fence* and you will see

> a wooden structure

The dictionary definition omits the word "is".

There's no passive voice here.  "Made" is an adjective, formed from the past participle.

---

Let's look at the passive voice.

> I made this birthday cake.
>
> This birthday cake was made by me.

That last sentence uses the passive voice.

Comment: What I understood is that the header of the sentence was cashed, I mean this part "a fence is" and the rest of the sentence began from "a structure made of wood" thank you for your help even I didn't understand why this is not a passive voice anyway thank you all..